# How to report that a Sentinel-2 Level-1C granule is not georeferenced accurately (Google Earth Engine)

Tags: google-earth-engine, sentinel-2

I made some greenest pixel composites in GEE and they looked odd--like a river showing up in a town. I found that a granule from 2015 is not georeferenced accurately...then I found another from the same date.

https://code.earthengine.google.com/006fba9fa62c4b9912d38744c9a19d65

Is there a process for reporting this sort of thing?

Comment: As per [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/208651/67264) you can notify the ESA using the Copernicus help desk.

Comment: I followed the link to the "ESA helpdesk" that was mentioned in the post you provided. They replied that they are the wrong team to contact and I should use this email address instead eosupport@copernicus.esa.int I wanted to comment this on the original post but I don't have enough reputation points or something like that.