# Satellite imagery tiles not aligned

Tags: arcgis-desktop, imagery, satellite

I downloaded LISS4 satellite imagery of my study area, consisting of multiple tiles. I digitize some area from one of the tiles but I found out that the other tiles don't seem to align with the first one when I started to digitize an area which falls on the 2nd tile .

I am new with satellite imagery, I just want to know if there are any processes that need to be done before working with satelite imagery.

Is there any way of correcting this problem?

Note: Both the tiles are of same projections .[image: 1st Tile]

[image: 2nd Tile]

Comment: I dont know the reason for your missalignment but to fix it you can try something like: [Sentinel-2 satellite images not aligning properly](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/208647/sentinel-2-satellite-images-not-aligning-properly)

Comment: @BERA Thank you i will try this suggestion.